# Ffmpeg SCRIPT: image sequence conversion to tiff

Tags: image, shell, sequence

I have a problem with a simple script
in the FOLDER have image sequence in .jpg
all jpg files I would like to convert them to tiff

this is my script, but not work fine:

```
for I in *.jpg; do ffmpeg -start_number 000001 -f image2 -i "$I" -c:v tiff TIFF/"%6d.tif";
```

when I run the script, 
ffmpeg for every jpg continually reboots 
and in the output directory I have only one tif converted.

how I do not restart for each jpg ffmpeg?

thank you

Comment: Which TIFF file is converted?  The *first* one that should get processed, or the *last* one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ffmpeg, the start number generally refers to your input images, not the output image.  FFMPEG will also take `*.jpg` as input using the `glob` option (check the [docs](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Examples) rather than looping through yourself and calling it 1000 times.

Currently, your script will generate the same tiff file for each of the different jpegs that you are calling, because you are just re-calling it with the same parameters.

You could try putting `$I.tif` at the end instead of `"%6d.tif"`;

```
for I in *.jpg; do
    ffmpeg -i "$I"  -c:v tiff TIFF/${I%%.jpg}.tif
done
```

This part `${I%%.jpg}` takes your original file name and strips off the `.jpg`

In Imagemagick you can simply do:

```
convert *.jpg tiff
```